# How to add authentication for the razor pages in the ASP.Net Core SPA template that uses IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net, authentication, razor, single-page-application, razor-pages

When we create a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Application with Angular and individual user accounts authentication, we get a solution that uses IdentityServer4 for authentication. For the Angular side, everything wired up correctly regarding the user login flow.

I would like to build a hybrid app, where I can use the Razor server rendered pages as well. I would like to be able to decorate a Razor page model like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class TestModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
}
```

If the user calls the ~/Test URL, the server should check if the user is currently logged in and redirect to the login page if not.

Can someone please tell me how I need to configure the startup.cs so that I can use IdentityServer auth for the SAP side and the razor pages at the same time?

This is the Startup class as generated by the template:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have identity wired up in startup.cs ?

Comment: Yes, that is automatically wired up by the template code.

Comment: Can you post the startup code that relates to Identity?  I'm doing exactly what you want in my current project, without any issues.

Comment: Neil, I've added the content from the startup class. But that is really what you get when you create a new ASP.Net SPA with Angular Client inside. The template even creates a Pages folder in the root dir. The pages are working, only I can't secure them with an [Authorize] attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The Docs below is probably what you're searching for. You can configure Authorization for Razor pages from the `Startup.cs` file using an overload of `AddRazorPages()` in the `ConfigureServices` method

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#allow-anonymous-access-to-a-folder-of-pages

**UPDATE**

To redirect users to a login page, I believe you need to specify a login path for the authentication cookie. Adding the below code snippet to your `Startup.cs` (or wherever you configure the project) below should work:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
{
    config.LoginPath = "/account/login";
});
```

Happy coding!

Comment: That doesn't change anything. I already decorated my page with [Authorize] (see above) so the user will get a 401 unauthorized. My question is how can I force a redirect to the login if a user is unauthorized.

Comment: @ozerfrettelter Check my updated answer, that should solve the problem